# how to change the home, back, windows button in Android cellphone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, back-button, android-homebutton

I'm trying to change the function of the three main buttons of an android cellphon. is there a mathod or funcation to do that because I search the internet, but not sure what write to find my answer. So any help will be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to change the behavior only when your app is currently opened or system-wide?

Comment: While you can change the back behavior in your apps, and capture the home button by being installed and selected as the luancher, complete alteration can only be accomplished my modifying the sources of Android, which requires being able to create *and install* a fully functional build (both of which can present device specific challenges).  The code in question is located in a privileged app called SystemUI - see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/SystemUI/

Comment: "ByteHamster" Yes, I want to change the behavior only when my app is working. "Chris Stratton" I can't see what I need in the file you told me to check.